# I need help identifying a kid cart for bicycles

Tags: accessories, trailer

I have two bikes set up for a tow cart with the pictured hook up. It shows a square insert:

[image: cart hook up]

We want to buy a kid cart that uses the same fitting. Can anyone identify a manufacturer that has a same fitting?

Comment: Is there any brand info on the carts that fit the piece?  (I presume you already have carts that fit, and you're just looking for another.)

Comment: Appears to be an MEC brand product.

Comment: If you buy a new trailer it will come with a hitch. Additional hitches are usually not expensive.

Comment: Welcome, your question is nice and clean but I still suggest to take the Welcome [tour] to see the ways how this site is used as it is used differently than some discussions forums you might be familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

**I think I've found it**

It looks like a [Croozer](https://www.campfirecycling.com/product/croozer-bike-kid-trailer-square-hitch-p-1339.html) but you might want to check the dimensions.

**But**

The cost of a new hitch is far less than the difference in price between different trailers.  Fitting is trivial, you do it every time you take the wheel off to fix a puncture, so even swapping between hitches isn't too onerous.

It's far better to get the trailer you want given your budget, and get a spare hitch to fit that if necessary - one should come with the trailer. I paid £/€/$10-20 for my spare.

The only exception would be if you really need 2 trailers both to fit 2 bikes, and already have one.  If you've already got one, it should have a brand on it, though admittedly brands come and go.  Even if the brand has ceased to exist, searching for spares for that brand might tell you what else they fit.

A round hitch is far more common (Hamax style) IME, or the Burley style, but that's more expensive